# XPath multiple validation conditions with multiple XML tags

Tags: xml, validation, xpath

I'm trying to write an XPath validation expression to check the correctness of XML form shown below. I'd like to validate that:

- in case of `OperationType = 1` all fields in a single `User` node are filled
- in case of `OperationType = 2` at least `Login` field within respective `User` node is filled

I came up with following expression, but it works only if a single `User` node is present:

```
//wnio:Login!=''
and (//wnio:FirstName!='' or //wnio:OperationType!='1')
and (//wnio:LastName!='' or //wnio:OperationType!='1') 
and (//wnio:Email!='' or //wnio:OperationType!='1')
```

However, this validates a document positively if these fields are not empty in separate `User` tags.

I'd love to know if it's possible to validate these conditions in a structure similar to the following. I'd be grateful for any suggestions on how to handle this problem.

```
<wnio:Document>
    <wnio:Content>
        <wnio:SubmittedUsers>
            <wnio:User>
                <wnio:OperationType>1</wnio:OperationType>
                <wnio:FirstName>Adam</wnio:FirstName>
                <wnio:Login>adamnowak</wnio:Login>
                <wnio:Email>adamnowak@example.com</wnio:Email>
                <wnio:LastName>Nowak</wnio:LastName>
            </wnio:User>
            <wnio:User>
                <wnio:OperationType>2</wnio:OperationType>
                <wnio:FirstName/>
                <wnio:Login>testlogin</wnio:Login>
                <wnio:Email/>
                <wnio:LastName/>
            </wnio:User>
            <wnio:User>
                <wnio:OperationType>1</wnio:OperationType>
                <wnio:FirstName>John</wnio:FirstName>
                <wnio:Login>johnsmith</wnio:Login>
                <wnio:Email>johnsmith@example.com</wnio:Email>
                <wnio:LastName>Smith</wnio:LastName>
            </wnio:User>
        </wnio:SubmittedUsers>
        <wnio:AuthorityType>1</wnio:AuthorityType>
    </wnio:Content>
</wnio:Document>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like : 
`/wnio:Document/wnio:Content/wnio:SubmittedUsers/wnio:User[(wnio:OperationType = '1' and wnio:FirstName != '' and wnio:Login != '' and wnio:Email != '' and wnio:LastName != '') 
or (wnio:OperationType = '2' and wnio:Login != '')]`

Comment: @GGO - this works correctly! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the system I work with (ePUAP) the correct expression was:

```
not(/wnio:Dokument/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:SubmittedUsers/wnio:User[
(wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:Login = '') 
or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:FirstName= '') 
or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:LastName= '') 
or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:Email= '') 
or (wnio:OperationType='2' and wnio:Login= '')
])
```

which can be simplified to:

```
not(/wnio:Dokument/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:SubmittedUsers/wnio:User[
((wnio:OperationType='1' 
  and (wnio:Login = '' or wnio:FirstName= '' or wnio:LastName= '' or  wnio:Email= '')) 
or (wnio:OperationType='2' and wnio:Login= ''))
])
```

The above expression returns validation error for both conditions:

- in case of `OperationType = 1` all fields in a single `User` node must be
  filled
- in case of `OperationType = 2` at least `Login` field within
  respective `User` node must be filled

Comment: And your simplification looks suspiciously like my solution. :)

Comment: @Tomalak you're right - your solution helped me a lot and I really appreciate it. The main difference was that I had to negate all XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
/wnio:Document/wnio:Content/wnio:SubmittedUsers/wnio:User
[(w‌​nio:OperationType = '1' and wnio:FirstName != '' and wnio:Login != '' and wnio:Email != '' and wnio:LastName != '') 
or (wnio:OperationType = '2' and wnio:Login != '')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Select `wnio:User` elements that do not fulfill any of your your conditions and see if the resulting node set is empty or not.

```
//wnio:User[not(
  (
    wnio:OperationType = '1' 
    and wnio:Login > '' 
    and wnio:FirstName > '' 
    and wnio:LastName > ''
  )
  or (
    wnio:OperationType = '2' 
    and wnio:Login > '' 
  )
)]
```

If this selects nothing then all `wnio:User` elements fulfill your rules. To be extra sure you can add a condition that picks elements with an invalid `OperationType`.

Look at [XML Schema](https://www.w3.org/standards/xml/schema) (or [Relax NG](http://relaxng.org/)), as these have been made to enforce semantic rules in XML.

Comment: Unfortunately it allowed to pass a document with all empty fields and fields that were filled in separate rows for each column.

Comment: Yes, I checked it couple of times and eventually it worked after removing `not` in the 1st line. Thanks!

Comment: But now the test is no longer working. If you want to verify (validate) your XML, then you have to select the elements that do *not* match your rules, not the ones that do.

Comment: Well, I checked couple of more combinations of the documents and unfortunately none of them works. Take for example [this XML](https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/f62cb700f6d9bdb15ca3fc359c7acea7). I used your XPath and it returns all 4 nodes (in Notepad++), while on freeformatter.com only the wrong one. The evaluator in the system I work with (ePUAP) doesn't detect the error, however. It seems strange that 3 tools give different results for the same input.

Comment: Finally I solved this by using such expression: `not(/wnio:Dokument/wnio:TrescDokumentu/wnio:SubmittedUsers/wnio:User[(wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:Login = '') or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:FirstName= '') or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:LastName= '') or (wnio:OperationType='1' and wnio:Email= '') or (wnio:OperationType='2' and wnio:Login= '')])`